# Libgdx can I add Actions to Image?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am Trying to add action to the image but it's not working.
is it allowed to add action to images?
I tried to rotate it this way and it works:

```
mainButtons.center.rotateBy(5);
```

center is Image.
but when I try this way it is not working :

```
mainButtons.center.addAction(Actions.rotateBy(5));
```

I defined the image here:

```
public class MainButtons {
    public Viewport viewport;
    public Stage stage;
    public GameImages gameImages;

    public boolean centerPressed;

    public Image center;


    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    public static Table table;




    //Constructor.
    public MainButtons(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new StretchViewport(KidTele.V_WIDTH,KidTele.V_HIEGH,camera);
        stage = new Stage(viewport, spriteBatch);

        defineCenter();
    }
    public void defineCenter()
    {
        center=gameImages.centerImage();
        center.setBounds(viewport.getWorldWidth()/5f,viewport.getWorldHeight()/3f,viewport.getWorldWidth()/1.5f,viewport.getWorldHeight()/3f);
        center.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                centerPressed = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

                centerPressed = false;
            }
        });
        //center.setVisible(false);
        stage.addActor(center);
    }
}
```

And call it here:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);

        game.batch.begin();
        if(mainButtons.centerPressed) {
            mainButtons.center.addAction(Actions.rotateBy(5));
           // mainButtons.center.rotateBy(5);
        }

        game.batch.draw(background, 0, 0, gameport.getWorldWidth(), gameport.getWorldHeight());
        game.batch.end();
        mainButtons.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work. Look closely for anything else you changed. This Image is in a Stage and you're calling `stage.act()`, right?

Comment: I edited the question and you can see where I call it

Comment: Actions don't do anything if you don't call `stage.act()`.

Comment: call it inside the Playscreen class or mainButtons where I define the stage?

Comment: Thanks TenFour04 .I called stag.act in the playscreen render and It is working now but I used this action
mainButtons.center.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeOut(1), Actions.fadeIn(1))); 
not only the center image fade out and in but also the other images

Comment: Sounds like you have overridden `draw` in some of your other images and are not properly setting their color on the batch before drawing them.